# Is there a simple way to test services (like actionlib's axclient)?

Tags: ros, actionlib, roscpp, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to test a service connection as simply as possible (i.e. without setting up a dummy program).

Actionlib has to very nice axserver.py tool for this, which just displays the entries of an action and allows a user to respond to this.

I would like to have the same for services, some script that displays an arbitrary service in a simple gui and allows the user to reply to service calls.

Does something like this exist?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12092/is-there-a-simple-way-to-test-services-(like-actionlib%27s-axclient)?/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess, the answer is: Nobody knows anything. So I ripped axclient.py:

If anyone needs something like this. It is available here:
[sxserver](http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/freiburg_tools/fr_tools/scripts/sxserver/).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) on 2020-03-24**:
Since the link is outdated:
https://github.com/nobleo/rx_service_tools

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tend to just keep a rosh window open for things like this.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1